# How to get the id of button click event in a grid view when same page is opened in two different tabs using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid view with image buttons for each tr in asp and the same page is opened in two different tabs.

In First tab:

Button click event is performed for the first tr of the grid and the grid reloads after performing necessary functions.(first tr gets deleted)

In Second tab: (without re-loading the page)

When click event is performed on the button of the first tr which has got deleted in the first tab, id of the next tr is getting passed in command argument of asp button.

How can I resolve this issue when opened in two different tabs so that I can retrieve the id of the button click correctly in grid view?

Current Code:

Button link is asp :

```
 <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/btn_delete_sm.gif" ID="imgDelete"  runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to discontinue?');"  OnClick="btnDelete_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' />
```

VB:

```
Dim btnDetails As ImageButton = sender
Dim ID As String = btnDetails.CommandArgument.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it actually should not matter.

You not deleting by row "index", but are (should be) deleting by database PK id, and only one of those will ever exist.

So, say the user has two browsers open (or two tabs), it does  not really matter.

So, we are not (and don't) in general resolve the data by some row, but in fact use the 100% unquie database key id.

As a FYI, I often (in fact now in most cases) don't bother with the GV built in event model (on row index changed), or even use command arugment. (but, you can still do that if you wish).

Just drop in a plane jane regular button, and wire up the event this way:

Of course, normally, you can just double click on a button to add/create/wire up a click event. But, when you drop that button into the GV, you can't double click on the buttion in desinger to add the click event (since it nested inside of the GV).

So, you drag + drop the button into a template section, and then in markup simple type in

```
 onclick=
```

When you hit "=" button, then intelisense pops up this choice:

[image]

So, choose to create new event. You now have this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="40%"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" GridLines="none">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDescript" runat="server"
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description")  %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdDel" runat="server" Text="Delete"
                    CssClass="btn"
                    onclick="cmdDel_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And our code behind to load is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData()
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadData()

    Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataSource = MyrstP(cmdSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now we see/have this:

[image]

Ok, so now any button code does NOT operate on row index, but on the primary key

So, the button code to delete can be this:

```
Protected Sub cmdDel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Debug.Print("Row index click = " & gRow.RowIndex)
    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")
    Debug.Print("Hidden database PK value = " & intPK)

    ' delete the row from database
    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    MyrstP(cmdSQL, True)

    ' refresh grid after delete
    LoadData()

End Sub
```

So, in above, we use the hidden database ID. So, it will not matter if the user attempts to delete again.

Note how we using not really the row index, but in fact using the database "PK" id for the operations. Also, note VERY close, we NEVER expose or show the database PK id in the markup, nor is it even displayed in the GV. We used datakeys "id" setting for this. This not only means we NEVER did expose or have the database key client side in the browser, but better yet, it is a built-in feature of the gridview (or listview etc.) that manages the retrieval of the database PK (primary key) values, and it MUCH more secure, since such keys are never exposed to the client-side browser (good for security also).

So, the ONLY real challenge here is that of course the user might attempt to do some operation on a row that does not exist, but then again, you in code can and will deal with this.

So, if the operation was said to edit or do something else? Well, the code would find out/see that the row does not exist anymore.

And in above, like all developers, I became rather tired of typing what amounts to the same code over and over, so I used/have this helper routine:

```
Public Function MyrstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand,
                       Optional cmdOnly As Boolean = False) As DataTable
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
            mycon.Open()
            If cmdOnly Then
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function
```

but, say we dropped in an edit button to edit that row.

Say, we going to pop up an editor like this:

[image]

so now this edit button, will it still work if the other user deleted that row?

Sure, since the edit button code looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim intPK As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim cmdSQL = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    Dim rstHotel As DataTable = MyrstP(cmdSQL)

    If rstHotel.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Call EditOne(rstHotel)
    End If

End Sub
```

So, since all data operations are based on database PK, then it not going to matter.

now, of course one might want to pop up a message box or some such to tell the user that this row don't exist.

And of course, after editing, or even a delete, you re-fresh the gv anyway, and thus the user will still be ok (since after a edit, or edit attempt, or delete or anything else, you will/should/have to/good idea to refresh and re-load the GV anyway.

So, no, the wrong row will not be deleted assuming that you do EVERY data operation based on the PK (that is why we have a PK or so-called primary key for data operations - there is only ever one value that identifies the ONE data row in the database table.

So, for operations such as an edit, or some other operation, we have to pull/get/use/have the one row of data anyway, and if the row doesn't exist, then the code will/should/does/good idea/always check if the row exists anyway.

So, at the end of the day, why would the button control "id" matter? It is not going to matter anyway, since for each button I drop into the gv, we have ONE button click code stub for each button, and I don't even bother with the gv events.

However, for that given button, you are still free to add/use/have/enjoy/consider use of the command argument, and you can still pass values from the one gv row based on command arugment, but for the most part, once again, it should not matter since all database opearations are based on the database primary key value.

but, if for some other VERY strange reason (that you not shared with us), you do need/want to get the "id" of the control clicked, then of course you can do this in the above button click event:

```
Debug.Print("id of button click is = " & btn.ID)
Debug.Print("id of button click is = " & btn.ClientID)
```

so, first will give the button id, and 2nd will give the one generated for the given row click, and thus output is this:

```
id of button click is = cmdEdit
id of button click is = GridView1_cmdEdit_3
```